# Looking to add netstat functionality to Get-ADComputer powershell script

Tags: powershell, networking, active-directory, netstat

I'm using this Get-ADComputer script to find machines in a specific OU. Now I need to capture the inbound and outbound ports of machines in the script's output. I know this could be done with netstat, but I'm not sure how to include this in the script below. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

```
# Enter CSV file location
$csv = "C:\MyLocation"
# Add the target OU in the SearchBase parameter
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=xxx,OU=xx,OU=xx,OU=_xx,DC=xx,DC=xxx,DC=com" | Select Name | Sort-Object Name
$Computers = $Computers.Name
$Headers = "ComputerName,IP Address"
$Headers | Out-File -FilePath $csv -Encoding UTF8
foreach ($computer in $Computers)
{
Write-host "Pinging $Computer"
$Test = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable Err
if ($test -ne $null)
{
    $IP = $Test.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString
    $Output = "$Computer,$IP"
    $Output | Out-File -FilePath $csv -Encoding UTF8 -Append
}
Else
{
    $Output = "$Computer,$Err"
    $output | Out-File -FilePath $csv -Encoding UTF8 -Append
}
cls
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Get-NetTCPConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=win10-ps) to return TCP connections as a PowerShell object collection.

```
$netstat = Get-NetTCPConnection
$listeningPorts = $netstat | where state -eq 'Listen' | select -expand localport -unique
$netstat | where {$_.LocalPort -and $_.RemotePort -and $_.LocalAddress -ne '127.0.0.1'} |
    Select LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,
        @{n='Direction';e={
        if ($_.LocalPort -in $listeningPorts) {
        'Inbound'
        } 
        else { 'Outbound' }
        }
    }
```

---

If you want to run this remotely, provided you have PSRemoting enabled, you can utilize [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7):

```
$sb = {
$netstat = Get-NetTCPConnection
$listeningPorts = $netstat | where state -eq 'Listen' | select -expand localport -unique
$netstat | where {$_.LocalPort -and $_.RemotePort -and $_.LocalAddress -ne '127.0.0.1'} |
    Select LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,
        @{n='Direction';e={
        if ($_.LocalPort -in $listeningPorts) {
        'Inbound'
        } 
        else { 'Outbound' }
        }
    }
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -Scriptblock $sb
```

---

The `Where` criteria may need to change. My assumptions were to not include any ports numbered `0` or any connections made by `127.0.0.1`. Once listening ports are established, I assume they are used in inbound connections only.